# How to make torchaudio and librosa MFCC calculations equivalent?

Tags: python, pytorch, librosa, mfcc

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60492462/mfcc-python-completely-different-result-from-librosa-vs-python-speech-features) concerning the same type of issue between `librosa`, `python_speech_features` and `tensorflow.signal`.

I am trying to make `torchaudio` and `librosa` compute MFCC features with the same arguments and underlying methods. This is part of a transition from `librosa` to `torchaudio`.

Given:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

from librosa.feature import mfcc
from torchaudio.transforms import MFCC

sample_rate = 22050
audio = np.ones((sample_rate,), dtype=np.float32)

librosa_mfcc = mfcc(audio, sr=sr, n_mfcc=20, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512, power=2)

mfcc_module = MFCC(sample_rate=sr, n_mfcc=20, melkwargs={"n_fft": 2048, "hop_length": 512, "power": 2})
torch_mfcc = mfcc_module(torch.tensor(audio))
```

The `shape`s of `librosa_mfcc` and `torch_mfcc` are both `(20, 44)`, but the arrays themselves are different. For example, `librosa_mfcc[0][0]` is `-487.6101`, while `torch_mfcc[0][0]` is `-302.7711`.

I admit I am lacking a good amount of domain knowledge here, but am working through the [`librosa`](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/LibROSA.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html) and [`torchaudio`](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/LibROSA.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html) documentation and parameters to learn the different routes they take in MFCC calculation as well as the meaning behind each parameter. How do I make `torch_mfcc` have the same values as `librosa_mfcc`?

Comment: Differences are likely to be on the mel-spectrogram level, as that calculation is a key part of MFCC. So compare the parameters for thos. In librosa, make sure to check at least fmin, fmax, htk. In the mel spectrogram it may be possible to plot and reason about the differences as well

Comment: @jonnor I've tried standardizing the `fmin` and `fmax`, along with `htk` as both `true` and `false`. I still see differences in the array, could the implementation also potentially differ at the mel filter / STFT level? Looks like `torchaudio` doesn't provide ability to set kwargs for those, whereas `librosa` does. Will also try plotting like you suggested.

Comment: yes I think mel/STFT level differences can happen for sure. After the mels spectrogram is computed, there is "just" log transformation and then DCT-II to get MFCC. A good half-way point to determine where in the chain the errors start, at least

Comment: Not sure of MFCC, but i tried to match the output of MelSpectrogram. You can find the configuration and the code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10Iex_6WlQfEiIzT4oIZ0M_AocA_mv5rf?usp=sharing)   
Hope this helps.